# I need help understanding unintended dependency in this code

Tags: python, dictionary, dependencies

I have created this standalone example to isolate the behavior I'm trying to understand:

```
from pprint import pprint

TRADES_CLOSED = dict()
TRADES_ACTIVE = {
    '2010-01-08 12:00': [1, 'SHORT', 20000, '2010-01-08 12:00', 92.339],
    '2010-01-28 04:00': [2, 'LONG', 10000, '2010-01-28 04:00', 90.378],
    '2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
    '2010-01-29 04:00': [4, 'LONG', 20000, '2010-01-29 04:00', 90.164]}

TRADES_TEST = {k: TRADES_ACTIVE[k] for k in sorted(TRADES_ACTIVE)[-2:]}

pprint(TRADES_ACTIVE)
pprint(TRADES_TEST)

profit_long = TRADES_ACTIVE.pop([key for key, value in TRADES_TEST.items() if value[1] == "LONG"][0])
profit_long.extend(['2010-02-03 12:00', 91.278, 1464.54])

pprint(TRADES_ACTIVE)
pprint(TRADES_TEST)

TRADES_CLOSED[[key for key, value in TRADES_TEST.items() if value[1] == "LONG"][0]] = profit_long

pprint(TRADES_CLOSED)
```

I want to perform some operations on the last two entries in the `TRADES_ACTIVE` dictionary. Therefore, I create a new dictionary, called `TRADES_TEST`, which contains only the last two entries from `TRADES_ACTIVE`.

The code produces following output:

```
{'2010-01-08 12:00': [1, 'SHORT', 20000, '2010-01-08 12:00', 92.339],
 '2010-01-28 04:00': [2, 'LONG', 10000, '2010-01-28 04:00', 90.378],
 '2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
 '2010-01-29 04:00': [4, 'LONG', 20000, '2010-01-29 04:00', 90.164]}
{'2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
 '2010-01-29 04:00': [4, 'LONG', 20000, '2010-01-29 04:00', 90.164]}
{'2010-01-08 12:00': [1, 'SHORT', 20000, '2010-01-08 12:00', 92.339],
 '2010-01-28 04:00': [2, 'LONG', 10000, '2010-01-28 04:00', 90.378],
 '2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824]}
{'2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
 '2010-01-29 04:00': [4,
                      'LONG',
                      20000,
                      '2010-01-29 04:00',
                      90.164,
                      '2010-02-03 12:00',
                      91.278,
                      1464.54]}
{'2010-01-29 04:00': [4,
                      'LONG',
                      20000,
                      '2010-01-29 04:00',
                      90.164,
                      '2010-02-03 12:00',
                      91.278,
                      1464.54]}
```

`profit_long` list is created by popping the specific element of `TRADES_ACTIVE`. As expected `TRADES_ACTIVE` one element shorter. Then `profit_long` is being extended by three new values and used as an entry in the `TRADES_CLOSED` dictionary.

I do not understand, why extending `profit_long` affects the `TRADES_TEST` too. I was eyeballing this code for a long time and I can't figure it out. For me `profit_long` and `TRADES_TEST` are totally separate entities. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency is caused by the fact that your code sets up a dict of lists called `TRADES_ACTIVE`, and then it copies some of these lists to another dict of lists called `TRADES_TEST`. But when you assign a list to another variable, that assignment doesn't make copy of the list; it only copies the *reference to it*. To see this, after each of your `pprint()` calls, do for `k,v in somedict.items(): print (k, id(v))`. That will show you the id of each of your lists. When I did this, this is what I saw. First the code:

```
print("TRADES ACTIVE 1")
pprint(TRADES_ACTIVE)
print("TRADES ACTIVE 1")
for k,v in TRADES_ACTIVE.items(): print (k, id(v))

print("TRADES TEST 1")
pprint(TRADES_TEST)
print("TRADES TEST 1")
for k,v in TRADES_TEST.items(): print (k, id(v))
```

and then the output:

```
TRADES ACTIVE 1
{'2010-01-08 12:00': [1, 'SHORT', 20000, '2010-01-08 12:00', 92.339],
 '2010-01-28 04:00': [2, 'LONG', 10000, '2010-01-28 04:00', 90.378],
 '2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
 '2010-01-29 04:00': [4, 'LONG', 20000, '2010-01-29 04:00', 90.164]}
TRADES ACTIVE 1
2010-01-08 12:00 2236442430536
2010-01-28 04:00 2236442430856
2010-01-28 12:00 2236442431048
2010-01-29 04:00 2236442431176
TRADES TEST 1
{'2010-01-28 12:00': [3, 'SHORT', 10000, '2010-01-28 12:00', 89.824],
 '2010-01-29 04:00': [4, 'LONG', 20000, '2010-01-29 04:00', 90.164]}
TRADES TEST 1
2010-01-28 12:00 2236442431048
2010-01-29 04:00 2236442431176
```

As you can see, the matching keys in the two dicts point to the same list. Note that the id 2236442431176 recurs as the value of key "2010-01-29 04:00" in both lists.

Then your code makes another copy of one of these lists called `profit_long`. That also refers to the same list that occurs in as a value in both of the other dicts.

```
print("PROFIT_LONG")
print (id(profit_long))

PROFIT_LONG
2236442431176
```

and when you mutate that list (id 2236442431176 again) then the changes are visible in the two dicts because all three variables are referring to the same list.

To fix this, when you make a copy of the list object, copy the list and not just a reference to it. So, instead of

```
TRADES_TEST = {k: TRADES_ACTIVE[k] for k in sorted(TRADES_ACTIVE)[-2:]}
```

do

```
TRADES_TEST = {k: TRADES_ACTIVE[k][:] for k in sorted(TRADES_ACTIVE)[-2:]}
```